# How to pipe POST requests

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm a bit confused about how to pipe some data.

I've got some pipes working and chained such that I not have an output stream containing the data I want to input to a request POST

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8529,
    path: '/_api/cursor',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
}

var req = http.request(options);
```

I would normally just action 'mystreams2.pipe(req)' but how do I set the 'data.length' value ?

(I'm using the streams2 interface not the old stream format)

Answer (score 0):

By assumption that you don't have a massive amount of data in your buffer, you first need to collect the data in order to find its length.

```
var source = /* a readable stream */;
var data = '';

source.on('data', function(chunk) {
  data += chunk;
});
source.on('end', function() {
  var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8529,
    path: '/_api/cursor',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options);
  req.end(data);
});
```